# Is there an API which can tell Google Maps that my store is open or closed?

Tags: android, google-maps

We are looking at specific Google Map APIs which can help my android app publish whether the store is open or closed on a click on my app.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) of [Google Maps Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service).

The **Place Details Response** returns the following objects which could help on your implementation:

> - `Place` - This one have `business_status` field which *"indicates the operational status of the place, if it is a business. If no data exists, business_status is not returned. The allowed values include: **OPERATIONAL**, **CLOSED_TEMPORARILY**, and **CLOSED_PERMANENTLY**."* 
>   [ref here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#Place-business_status)
>   Here's also a youtube link that talks about this field: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSUHI2W9VVg

> For the following ones, I just included hyperlinks to the documentation for more details about their fields:

> - [`PlaceOpeningHours`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceOpeningHours)
> - [`PlaceOpeningHoursPeriod`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceOpeningHoursPeriod)
> - [`PlaceSpecialDay`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceSpecialDay)
> - [`PlaceOpeningHoursPeriodDetail`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#PlaceOpeningHoursPeriodDetail)

I would still recommend that you read through the documentation to learn more about this. Hope this helps!